# How do I convert the coordinates of a click to a tilemap position?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, tilemap, touch

How do you turn a tilemap (produced by TileD) for cocos2d where I can click on individual items and get a callback?

Is it just a case of converting captured touch and finding out where it is on the tilemap and then converting that to pixels  -- but that doesn't say what item was clicked on.

I have a tilemap of a city with buildings on it, and I'd like to be able to click or press on a specific building, get a callback.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I imagine you know where the player touched, and you know the location and contents of each tile. Why not just use that to deduce where the player touched? `return nearestPiece(tilemap, playerTouchPos).contents` or similar? (Or is *how to do that* what you're asking?)

Comment: I never heard of nearestPiece(tilemap, playerTouchPos) so I will have to research it more.

Comment: Yes, I am asking how to convert the contents of where a person has touched into finding out what I clicked on.  So if its building XYZ or whatever

Comment: All of that was [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudocode); only *structurally* illustrative. Don't bother looking the functions up: They don't exist (yet)! :)

Comment: Okay, this makes sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're getting your *pixel coordinates* and *tilemap coordinates* confused.

*Tile coordinates* count tiles.

[image: tile coordinates]

*Pixel coordinates* count pixels.

[image: pixel coordinates]

To convert from a pixel coordinate to a tile coordinate, divide the `click_x` by the tile `w`idth and the `click_y` by the and tile `h`eight, to get the tile coordinates `x` and `y`. (Discard the remainders to get an integer.)

The reason this works is pretty clear if we overlay the two coordinate systems:

[image: How the solution works]

In this above case, the pixel coordinates of the click would correspond to `6,4` in tile coordinates.

Once you know what tile position a click corresponds to, it should be trivial to find the contents of that tile.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was getting confused. Upvoted and accepted. Not enough cred to upvote at present.

Comment: I really need to get myself a basic tilemap built using dummy graphics and start coding up a touch interface and see what I can do with it -- I have no idea how I'm going to be able to keep a check of the multiple different kinds of buildings on the screen, but I'm sure with the notes you've given me I should get a bit further ahead.

Comment: @zardon I'm happy if this helped. In most languages, I see game programmers store tilemaps as two-dimensional arrays of "tile" objects (buildings, grass; whatever your tiles contain). That array's indices are then effectively tile coordinates, so `myTilemap[6][4]` would store whatever building stands at tile coordinates `6,4`. (I've never used cocos2d though; a more specific tutorial is probably easiest to follow.)

Comment: Even just theory is good enough, I can work out the cocos2d stuff; I agree array indicies will help.  I guess its case of having tilemaps and it tells the computer what is there, and the array indicies tell the computer what they do & what to call (function wise) and the pressing on the map tells the computer where the press occured.